# What is a word that describes when someone requires a certain quality of another person in order for them to be a possible dating option?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

This has been bugging me for the past 30 minutes. It's basically some sort of specific criteria you hold in order to even consider dating someone, like "My girlfriend has to like Star Wars," or "My Boyfriend needs to be muscular" or something of the like.
It's also a Slang term.

Comment: Are you asking a word for the set of criteria, the person who demands the criteria, or the general concept of having a set of criteria? You question is not that clear.

Comment: ***Deal-breaker*** (if the person *doesn't* have the quality).

Comment: Or a [***must-have***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/must-have)

Comment: I'd say the guy has _very specific taste_ in women.

Comment: Isn't this person just "selective"?

Comment: [*litmus test*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/litmus%20test)

Answer (score 2):

**Picky**--(adj.) The word describes someone whose standards for choosing a girlfriend or mate are so high that hardly anyone qualifies. 'Pickiness' (noun) is often used to explain the continued bachelorhood of very eligible men and women who remain single well into middle age and beyond. It's a refusal to settle or compromise one's lofty standards in romantic relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are thinking about, but if something does not meet minimum standards or requirements, you would say it is not ***up to snuff***.

> **up to snuff** <sub>and **up to scratch**</sub>
>   *Fig.* as good as is required; meeting the minimum requirements.
>   *Sorry, Tom. Your performance isn't **up to snuff**. You'll have to improve or find another job.*
>   *My paper wasn't **up to scratch**, so I got an F.*
>   <sub>[The Free Dictionary by Farlex](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+to+snuff)</sub>

Comment: That makes it sound like you actually think the person isn't good enough, rather than just not being the kind of person you want to date.  I might say a guy isn't *up to snuff* if he's boorish or abusive, but not if I just want someone who's more into Star Wars.

Comment: @MissMonicaE: I read *criteria* as a minimum standard. If it is just a matter of taste, I would use *cup of tea*.

Comment: the Star Wars example makes me think it's just a matter of taste (whereas *up to snuff* sounds like a semi-objective value judgment), although the muscles thing is more ambiguous.

Comment: @MissMonicaE: I have always understood different people would have different ideas for *snuff*. The subjective criteria itself could theoretically be applied objectively by a third party (such as a match maker, or online dating site).

Answer (score -1):

Not specific for dating, and not a slangword either, **"a prerequisite"** seems to fit.

> - "required or necessary as a prior condition" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prerequisite)
> - "something that you officially must have or do before you can have or do something else" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prerequisite)

e.g

- "Dedication is a prerequisite to promotion in our institution."
- "A strong personality is a prerequisite to leadership."
- "I'm not the type of guy who dates any woman. Sweetness and a quiet demeanor are prerequisites."

also appropriate, as Fumble Fingers suggested in his comment, "Sweetness and a quiet demeanor are **"a must-have"**.

Comment: "It's also a Slang term."

Comment: @CarlSmith  "prerequisite" a slang-word ?

Comment: Why the downvote?  It would be helpful to say why.

Comment: @CarlSmith's comment was probably intended to point out that you did not include the criterion that the word was supposed to be slang ('prerequisite' is definitely not slang).